# Java, GUI changes everything when setText() of JLabel is used

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel

When I change my text of my JLabel, my whole GUI positioning of elements are changed. I'm new with GUIs so my knowledge is limited on what it is doing.

```
package GUI;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.tri_voltage.md.util.Tools;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JButton b1 = new JButton("1"),b2=new JButton("2"),b3=new JButton("3"),b4=new JButton("4"),b5=new JButton("5"),b6=new JButton("6");
    JLabel l1= new JLabel("Label 1"),l2= new JLabel("Label 2"),l3=new JLabel("Label 3"),l4=new JLabel("Label 4"),l5=new JLabel("Label 5"),l6=new JLabel("Label 6");
    JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(), adminPane = new JPanel(), messagePane=new JPanel();
    JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    private final int HEIGHT_0 = 0,HEIGHT_1=30,HEIGHT_2=60;
    private final int JBUTTON_WIDTH = 100,JBUTTON_HEIGHT = 25,JBUTTON_RIGHT = 305,JBUTTON_LEFT = 0;
    private final int JLABEL_WIDTH =50,JLABEL_HEIGHT =25,JLABEL_LEFT=0,JLABEL_RIGHT=150;
    private final int JPANEL_WIDTH = 1000,JPANEL_HEIGHT=1000;

    public GUI() {
        load();
    }
    public void load() {
        setTitle("Employee Console");
        setSize(JPANEL_WIDTH,JPANEL_HEIGHT);

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainPane = Tools.createPanel(0, 0, JPANEL_WIDTH, 700, new GridBagLayout());
        adminPane = Tools.createPanel(0, 700, JPANEL_WIDTH, 300, "Admin Console", new GridBagLayout());
        messagePane = Tools.createPanel(105, 0, 200, 90, new GridBagLayout());
        loadButtons();
        loadLabels();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
        layeredPane.setSize(1000, 1000);
        add(layeredPane);
        //refresh();
    }
    public void loadButtons() {
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.weightx = 0.12;
        constraints.gridx = 2;
        constraints.ipady = 0;
        constraints.ipadx = 0;

        b1 = Tools.createButton(JBUTTON_LEFT, 0, JBUTTON_WIDTH, JBUTTON_HEIGHT, "Button 1", new ButtonListener(this));
        b2 = Tools.createButton(JBUTTON_LEFT, 30, JBUTTON_WIDTH, JBUTTON_HEIGHT, "Button 2", new ButtonListener(this));
        b3 = Tools.createButton(JBUTTON_LEFT, 60, JBUTTON_WIDTH, JBUTTON_HEIGHT, "Button 3", new ButtonListener(this));
        b4 = Tools.createButton(JBUTTON_RIGHT, 0, JBUTTON_WIDTH, JBUTTON_HEIGHT, "Button 4", new ButtonListener(this));
        b5 = Tools.createButton(JBUTTON_RIGHT, 30, JBUTTON_WIDTH, JBUTTON_HEIGHT, "Button 5", new ButtonListener(this));
        b6 = Tools.createButton(JBUTTON_RIGHT, 60, JBUTTON_WIDTH, JBUTTON_HEIGHT, "Button 6", new ButtonListener(this));
        mainPane.add(b1);
        mainPane.add(b2);
        mainPane.add(b3);
        mainPane.add(b4);
        mainPane.add(b5);
        mainPane.add(b6);
        layeredPane.add(mainPane,1);
    }

    public void loadLabels() {
        l1 = Tools.createLabel(JLABEL_LEFT,HEIGHT_0, JLABEL_WIDTH, JLABEL_HEIGHT, l1.getText());
        l2 = Tools.createLabel(JLABEL_LEFT,HEIGHT_1, JLABEL_WIDTH, JLABEL_HEIGHT, l2.getText());
        l3 = Tools.createLabel(JLABEL_LEFT,HEIGHT_2, JLABEL_WIDTH, JLABEL_HEIGHT, l3.getText());
        l4 = Tools.createLabel(JLABEL_RIGHT,HEIGHT_0, JLABEL_WIDTH, JLABEL_HEIGHT, l4.getText());
        l5 = Tools.createLabel(JLABEL_RIGHT,HEIGHT_1, JLABEL_WIDTH, JLABEL_HEIGHT, l5.getText());
        l6 = Tools.createLabel(JLABEL_RIGHT,HEIGHT_2, JLABEL_WIDTH, JLABEL_HEIGHT, l6.getText());
        messagePane.add(l1);
        messagePane.add(l2);
        messagePane.add(l3);
        messagePane.add(l4);
        messagePane.add(l5);
        messagePane.add(l6);
        layeredPane.add(messagePane,0);
    }
    public void refresh() {
        repaint();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {

        }
    }

}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    private final GUI gui;
    private String screen = "main";


    ButtonListener(GUI gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
            case "Button 1":
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(),"Button 1 has been pressed!");
                break;

            case "Button 2": 
                gui.l1.setText(null);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Tools:

```
package com.tri_voltage.md.util;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

import com.tri_voltage.md.util.MediaType;

public class Tools {

    private final static Font defaultFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 15);

    private final static ImageIcon defaultImageIcon = null;//TODO: Find a suitable image icon

    public static ImageIcon loadMediaTypeImageIcon(String type) {
        return loadMediaTypeImageIcon(MediaType.valueOf(type));
    }

    public static ImageIcon loadMediaTypeImageIcon(MediaType type) {
        return loadImageIcon(type.getImagePath());
    }

    public static ImageIcon loadImageIcon(String path) {
        if (path.equalsIgnoreCase("NONE"))
            return defaultImageIcon;
        return new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path)));
    }

    public static String readLine(InputStream stream, long lineNumber) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            for (long l = 0; l < lineNumber; l ++)
                reader.readLine();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            return line;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the last line number within the file (fileLocation) that is being called.
     * @param fileLocation
     * @return The last line number of the file. <b>(NOTE: Keep in mind that the first line number of a file is 0!)</b>
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static int getLastLineNumber(String location) {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File(location)));
            lnr.skip(9223372036854775807L);
            return lnr.getLineNumber();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static JPanel createPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, String title, LayoutManager layout, JComponent... components) {
        JPanel panel = createPanel(x, y, width, height, layout);
        if (title != null || title != "")
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        if (components != null)
            for (JComponent component : components)
                if (component != null)
                    panel.add(component);
        return panel;
    }

    public static JPanel createPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, LayoutManager layout, JComponent... components) {
        JPanel panel = createPanel(x, y, width, height, layout);
        if (components != null)
            for (JComponent component : components)
                if (component != null)
                    panel.add(component);
        return panel;
    }

    public static JPanel createPanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, LayoutManager layout) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        panel.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        return panel;
    }

    public static JButton createButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, String title, ActionListener listener) {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        if (title == null || title == "")
            button.setText("Button");
        else
            button.setText(title);
        button.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        if (listener != null)
            button.addActionListener(listener);
        return button;
    }

    public static JTextField createTextField(int x, int y, int width, int height, String actionCommand, KeyListener keyListener, ActionListener actionListener) {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        if (keyListener != null)
            textField.addKeyListener(keyListener);
        if (actionListener != null)
            textField.addActionListener(actionListener);
        if (actionCommand != null)
            textField.setName(actionCommand);
        return textField;
    }

    public static JTextField createTextField(int x, int y, int width, int height, String actionCommand, KeyListener listener) {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        if (listener != null)
            textField.addKeyListener(listener);
        if (actionCommand != null)
            textField.setName(actionCommand);
        return textField;
    }

    public static JCheckBox createCheckBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, String name, ActionListener listener) {
        JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox(name);
        checkBox.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        if (listener != null)
            checkBox.addActionListener(listener);
        return checkBox;
    }

    public static JComboBox<String> createComboBox(int x, int y, int width, int height, String actionCommand, String[] options, ActionListener listener) {
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(options);
        comboBox.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        if (actionCommand != null)
            comboBox.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
        return comboBox;
    }

    public static JLabel createLabel(int x, int y, int width, int height, String title, Color background, Color foreground) {
        JLabel label = createLabel(x, y, width, height, title, background);
        label.setForeground(foreground);
        return label;
    }

    public static JLabel createLabel(int x, int y, int width, int height, String title, Color background) {
        JLabel label = createLabel(x, y, width, height, title);
        label.setBackground(background);
        return label;
    }

    public static JLabel createLabel(int x, int y, int width, int height, String title) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        if (title != null || title != "")
            label.setText(title);
        label.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        return label;
    }

    public static JMenu createMenu(String name, JMenuBar parent, MenuListener listener) {
        JMenu menu = new JMenu(name);
        menu.addMenuListener(listener);
        parent.add(menu);
        return menu;
    }

    public static JMenu createMenu(String name, JMenuBar parent) {
        return createMenu(name, parent, null);
    }

    public static JMenuItem createMenuItem(String name, JMenu parent, ActionListener listener) {
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(name);
        item.addActionListener(listener);
        parent.add(item);
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * @return the defaultfont
     */
    public static Font getDefaultfont() {
        return defaultFont;
    }

}
```

Here are the pictures attached:
   Before Button 2 is pressed:
[image]

After Button 2 is pressed:
[image]

Comment: 1) What code is contained within the Tools class? 2) Consider reading on Swing layout managers.

Comment: wouldn't you need to adjust button size, if the label size is too big? I imagine that the label can't overrun into an adjacent label, or similar.

Comment: Coffee, I changed it to the exact same text and and to nothing and the same thing happen.

Comment: Because Coffee is wrong -- but again: what is this Tools class?

Comment: In `loadButtons` you create a `GridBagConstraints` as well as set some of it's properties. But you never actually make use of it (use it as constraints when adding your buttons to the container). I suggest reading up on how `GridBagLayout` works. Also, rather than trying to do everything in 1 panel/layout, use multiple panels with different layouts to achieve the look you want.

Comment: Okay, I was confused about the constraints cause when I did add them, I saw no change what so ever.

Comment: I guess I'm typing with invisible ink. It sure would be nice to know about this Tools class, but until I can create a comment that the original poster can or will read and respond to, I guess we'll never know.

Comment: on a "admin" note, try to crop pictures so we don't have to scroll so much , those pics are way too large

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, I was on my phone at I posted. I couldn't upload.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some containers like layout and add elements to it. This makes sure that the elements are fixed. If u did nt use any container then while u resize all you elements wont get resized along with it. This is the problem here also. When your label size changes the whole contents are affected.

Just see this link to know more about learning layouts.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_layouts.htm